# How to restrict function parameters using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Let's assume four functions `f1,f2,f3,f4 :: SomeMonad m => m a -> m a` where `f1` and `f2` are conceptually related and similarly `f3` and `f4`.

Now it is possible to write a function `f :: SomeMonad m => (m a -> m a) -> m a` that can take any of the `f1..f4` as input. And then it is possible to write, say, `f1 $ f f2`.

The question is, how to write a function `g` such that it accepts only `f1` or `f2` as a parameter? We should be able to write `f4 $ g f1` and ghc should deny `g f3`.

If I try to add a `class`, say `:: (SomeMonad m, Some_G_class a) =>`, the return type `a` is also constrained and then `f4` cannot be applied. And similarly it seems that the `m` cannot be modified.

---

**Late Addition**

The answers by Daniel Wagner and leftroundabout both seem to be useable.

Here is more about the actual (and practical) problem.

- The underlying lib contains tens of functions returning `m a`.
- The lib has been build so that functions can be chained, e.g. with `(.)` like  `f1 . f2 . f3`.
- Conceptually, there is about five to ten subsets of those functions, subsets overlapping. The functions should be chaineable within each subset but not with functions from the other subsets.

**Using Proxies**

It seems that

```
data Type = A | B | C ... | H
data Proxy (ty :: Type) = Proxy
```

could be used to classify functions. To handle overlapping useage, a function call like

```
h1 :: SomeMonad t m => Either (Proxy A) (Proxy B) -> m t -> m t
h1 (Left (Proxy :: Proxy A) mt = ..
h1 (Right (Proxy :: Proxy B) mt = ..
```

could do it. But what if there are functions belonging to `A, B, C` and `D`? Maybe there is something like `OneOf` or `Any` that would work here?

**Using RankNTypes**

It seems that the `SpecificMonad`-constraint (restriction?) starts to propage to the usage sites of the functions `f3` and `f4` (that is, all over). I feel that if I try to manage the 5-10 overlapping function sets, there will be  serious difficulties with those constraints propagating every where. Is this the case?

So we need a function to make coercing, maybe something like

```
fg :: (SomeMonad t m1, SpecificMonad t m2) => m2 t -> m1 t
fg a = pure $ fromSpecM a
```

and atm assuming `SomeMonad` has `pure`. In my case I cannot add `fromSpecM` to the class-methods of `SomeMonad` but maybe it is ok in `SpecificMonad`. And my first trials along this way are still too simple so that I could see if this is doable. It may well be that I'm not seeing something very obvious here.

In a way, `SpecificMonad` shouldn't have any additional methods and it should just work as a "local env/fix/hack" not affecting other parts of the code. Thus, is there other ways to accomplish something like `fg`?

Comment: I think that in Haskell functions should be seen as *blackboxes*. Since there are a zillion ways to construct exactly the same function (partial application, lambda expressions, etc.). So it looks to me it would be bad design to do such "whitelisting".

Comment: In my case the whitelisting could be used to add some guarantees that are now left to the user of a lib. There are many conceptually overlapping sets of functions and thus the situation is a bit more complex than in the q above. In practice, I cannot change the lib that allows "too many usages for functions" to construct conceptually in-approriate function applications. But maybe a wrapper for the lib that would define appropriate data-types that can be "classified" and that would have a function producing `m a`.

Comment: Haskell does not have dependent types, hence substituting a subexpression like `f1` with another one of the same type like `f4` is always possible. You need to assign those two functions different types, e.g. using a `newtype` wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f4` all have the same type signature, then the type system can't distinguish between them (duh), so you also can't restrict which of them should be valid.

So before you can possibly accomplish your goal, you need some distinction in the signatures. Probably the most sensible way is to refine the monad-class constraint:

```
class SomeMonad m => SpecificMonad m

f1, f2 :: SomeMonad m => m a -> m a     -- same as before
f3, f4 :: SpecificMonad m => m a -> m a -- more restrictive
```

(You wouldn't need to change the implementations here, because `SpecificMonad` guarantees `SomeMonad`.)

Now, `f :: SomeMonad m => (m a -> m a) -> m a` by itself does not enforce that the argument fulfills any particular constraint – whatever function you pass in would merely add its constraint to the `SomeMonad` m constraint that `f` brings itself, i.e.

```
f f1 :: SomeMonad m => m a
f f3 :: SpecificMonad m => m a -- because `SomeMonad` is superclass, we don't need
                               -- to mention it, but it's actually implicit constraint
```

are both well-typed.

You can however enfore that `f` will only accept a function with a particular, *not too specific* constraint. That requires Rank-2 polymorphism<sup>†</sup>:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}

g :: SomeMonad m => (∀ μ . SomeMonad μ => μ a -> μ a) -> m a
g φ = f φ
```

Now, you can write `g f1`, because `f1` is a polymorphic function that works on any `SomeMonad`. You cannot however write `g f3`, because `f3` is too picky in what monads it can operate with, and even if the outer `m` that `g f3` is supposed to be used with does fulfill the `SpecificMonad` constraint<sup>‡</sup>, `g` will not allow its argument to access that information.

---

Of course, to now use `f3` and `f4` in any other, *legitimate* setting, such as `f4 $ g f1`, you will have to add instances for `SpecificMonad` to any monad they should work with. These are one-liners like

```
instance SpecificMonad []
instance SpecificMonad Maybe
```

(provided that these have `SomeMonad` instances already).

---

<sup>†</sup>

Written without Unicode:

```
g :: SomeMonad m => (forall m' . SomeMonad m' => m' a -> m' a) -> m a
g = f
```

<sup>‡</sup><sub>As it must, if you want to write `f4 $ g f1`.</sub>

Comment: This raised an extra q about the constraints induced by writing things like `f3` in your answer. I made a `class Hmm` and `class SHmm` to represent envs  `SomeMonad` and `SpecificMonad`, and then wrote functions `f, g, f1,.., f4` to check types with ghci. The type of `f4 $ g f1` will be specific (it has constraint `SHmm`). I'm suspecting that in practice I have to be able to turn `SHmm` back to `Hmm` (because otherwise I should put `SHmm` into quite many places). In small setting this might do but I'm suspecting that this doesn't scale to the problem I'm facing (I'll update the q a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can get away with a simple phantom type parameter. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data Type = A | B
data Id (ty :: Type) a = Id a

f1, f2 :: Id A a -> Id A a
f1 = id
f2 = id

f3, f4 :: Id B a -> Id B a
f3 = id
f4 = id
```

In ghci, we can see that `f1` and `f2` combine just fine, as do `f3` and `f4`, but not e.g. `f1` and `f3`:

```
Main> :t f1 . f2
f1 . f2 :: Id 'A a -> Id 'A a
Main> :t f3 . f4
f3 . f4 :: Id 'B a -> Id 'B a
Main> :t f1 . f3

<interactive>:1:6: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘'B’ with ‘'A’
      Expected type: Id 'B a -> Id 'A a
        Actual type: Id 'B a -> Id 'B a
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘f3’
      In the expression: f1 . f3
```

Comment: I made `data Proxy (ty :: Type) a = Proxy` and this made it possible to write `f` and `g` variants that work in the setting given in q above. And `h1 :: SomeMonad t m => Proxy A -> m t -> m t` etc.  Scaling is something that is making my head itch. (I'll make a late addition to the q about scaling in a more complex/larger env that is closer to the actual practical problem I'm facing.)